# How to embed chart.js in angular-seed

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts, angular-seed

I'm trying to use ng2-charts in an SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-2 project and I get the following error

**Error**: ng2-charts configuration issue: Embedding Chart.js lib is mandatory

Now I embedded chart.js in tools/config/project.config.ts

```
{ src: 'chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js', inject: 'libs'}
```

it is working as expected. Now I built my project and I get the following error in build process

```
Error on fetch for ng2-charts.js
```

[image]

I have done some research and kept the following code in tools/config/seed.config.ts

```
SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG->paths --> 'ng2-charts' : 'node_modules/ng2-charts/ng2-charts.js'
```

then the build was success, then I copied dist/prod folder in my tomcat server My App didn't loaded and I get the following error in browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.map is not a function
```

Doing research, but unable to find it. Can any of you help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `{ src: 'chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js', inject: 'libs'}` in tools/config/project.config.ts  -> this.NPM_DEPENDENCIES

Add `'ng2-charts' : 'node_modules/ng2-charts/ng2-charts.js'` in tools/config/seed.config.ts ->

in `SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV` // for dev

in `SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG`  // for prod

Note: angular version should be greater 2.3 // I got error for older versions